# Creating a gets function that returns a char* on return pressed using a getchar function

Tags: c, gets

I had this problem for a while. I cannot create a gets(int maxChar) function that allows the user to get a char* using a get_char() function.

My current code:

```
char* gets(int maxChar) {
    char a;
    char* b;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<maxChar; i = i + 1){
        a = getchar();
        if (a != 0x0D) {putchar(a);} else {puts("\r\n");break;}
        b[sizeof(b)] = a;
    }
    if (sizeof(b) > maxChar-1) {puts("\r\n");}
    return b;
    //if (b[sizeof(b)-1] != '')
}
```

the get_char() function works perfectly.

Full kernel.c: https://pastebin.com/3bqTbHsv

Comment: `b[sizeof(b)] = a;` - __WHERE__ is `a` supposed to be stored?? Did you allocate enough memory for it?  Also, `sizeof(b)` is a constant.

Comment: You have a pointer `b` but you never make it point anywhere! It seems to me you should get a few beginners books and kind of start over from the beginning, as there are many basic mistakes in your code.

Comment: (1) `b` is not initialized; when you say `b [`...`]` you have no idea where that is. (2) All the characters go to `b [sizeof (b)]` (which on most systems is either `b [4]` or `b [8]`). (3) You seem to be believe that `sizeof` something can ever change; it cannot, it's a constant. (3) You *say* that you want to use a function named `get_char()` but you don't. (4) If `getchar()` and `putchar()` are the real well-known `getchar()` and `putchar()` then their usage is strange -- character echoing has ususually happened long before `getchar()` seeis it.

Comment: ForceBru, which one? 'if (sizeof(b)...' or 'b[sizeof(b)]...'?

Comment: I used some custom asm to make putchar and getchar

Comment: If I cant use sizeof(b) to add new item to a char*, how do I add a new char* to b?

Comment: I think I initialized them correctly, char a; char* b; int i; if not, then how/where?

Comment: *"I think I initialized them correctly":* `i` is initialized to 0 by `i = 0`. `a` is initialized by `a = getchar()`. But `b`? Where does `b` get a value? (And you seem to confuse declarations and initializations.) *"If I cant use `sizeof(b)` to add new item to a `char*`, how do I add a new `char*` to `b`":* there are many books providing gentle introduction to C; I recommend *The C Programming Language*, 2nd Edition (<-- it's important to be 2nd Edition), by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

Comment: If you’re doing this as a learning exercise, great. But for anyone getting a `gets() is deprecated` error and wondering how to solve the same problem,  `fgets()` is in the standard library.

Comment: Do you just attempt attempt to get the code running or actually *understand* why it does not ? Cause I fear you actually don't understand a few core concepts of c programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an educated guess at what you were attempting to do.  It includes some explanations, and a calling example:

```
char* _gets(int maxChar) // change name to avoid conflict with library 'gets'
{
    //char a; //addresses concern pointed out in comments. 
    int a;    //variable is used by function that can return EOF (-1)
    int i=0; //

    char* b = calloc(maxChar + 1, 1);//point pointer to memory (that it owns)
    if(b) //test for success before going on
    {
        for(i = 0; i<maxChar-3; i = i + 1) // -3 to leave room for \r\n\0
        {

            a = getchar();
            if ((a != 0x0D) && (a != EOF)) 
            {
                putchar(a);
                b[i]=a;// place char into string accumulator
            }
            else break;// either EOF or <ENTER> occurred 

        }   // no need for else in this implementation as we can handle
            // the clean up once the conditions are met by outputting 
            // user's entries, then preparing your string (array) for return
        puts("\r\n");
        b[i++]='\r';
        b[i++]='\n';
        b[i++]='\0';
    }
    else return NULL;//failed to allocate memory.  leave

    return b;  // return  b (now a string)
    //if (b[sizeof(b)-1] != '')  // not sure what this was for
}

int main(void)
{ 
    char *strArray = _gets(10);//creates memory for strArray
    if(strArray) //use only if not NULL
    { 
        printf("The array contains: %s", strArray );
        free(strArray );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question so you have access to kernel.c

Comment: And not using stdio.h

Comment: I did not intend to write your final implementation, just provide some insight so that you could do it.

Comment: But, what does it return? text\r\n\0?

Comment: Yes, the very last steps of the function output the user's `<ENTER>` keystroke (`\r\n` ), which you can see on the display, then, the characters: `\r\n\0` are each placed into the `array` string one at a time, which completes the requirements for a string, making it usable as an argument in the `printf()` statement, which sends the string to `stdout`, essentially repeating what was entered in the first place.

Comment: Note also, the function truncates the string if more than `maxChar - 3` characters are entered, so you can enter as many characters as you want without overflowing the `char *b = ...` variable.

Comment: This still has the bug that `a` is char, while `getchar()` returns an int, so it won't be able to see some return values of getchar() (such as EOF).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Agreed.  Edited per comment.  Thanks.  (fyi, my `getchar()` implementation is defined as follows: _Returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by the standard input. If the stream is at end-of-file or a read error occurs, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the function returns EOF (-1)._  ...So only -1 will be returned in the event of any error.

Comment: Lee, if you know asm, I encourage you to go to the X-DOS gitbub project page. ling is in question

Comment: @RaduUngureanu - If you want Lee to see your previous comment, you need to resend it and preceed his moniker with the ampersand.  ( `@LeeDanielCrocker` )

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker if you know asm, I encourage you to go to the X-DOS gitbub project page. link is in question

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char* b;
```

to

```
char* b = (char *)malloc(maxChar);
```

and

```
b[sizeof(b)] = a;
```

to

```
b[i] = a;
```

Also, change

```
if (sizeof(b) > maxChar-1) {puts("\r\n");}
```

to

```
if (i > maxChar-1) {puts("\r\n");}
```

The changes made are:

1. You have created a pointer, but have not allocated any memory. Hence the `malloc` statement.
2. `sizeof(b)` will always be `4` for a 32-bit compiler. You need the array index, given by `i`.
3. Same as 2.

These are the basic changes you need to make, without any change to your logic.

Comment: And also make many more changes... This answer is incomplete *and* it doesn't explain anything.

Comment: No prototype found for function 'malloc'?

Comment: Include `stdlib.h`

Comment: Thanks! Still, Then I just click return, it puts: @(newline char)@(newline char).

Comment: For fun,consider `if (i > maxChar-1)` vs. `if (i >= maxChar)`. The first may overflow with pathological input `maxChar == INT_MIN`.  The 2nd _never_ overflows.

Comment: *Do not* cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.